# Slow performance in LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have this t-sql query that is from an old system that run on Cold Fusion. This query takes less than one second to return the records.

```
select  dateDiff(month, dateAdd(hour, 11, createdAt), {ts '2015-02-28 23:59:59'}) p, count(*) c 
from    account 
where   createdAt <= {ts '2015-02-28 23:59:59'} 
and accountType = 'business' 
and dateDiff(month, dateAdd(hour, 11, createdAt), {ts '2015-02-28 23:59:59'}) <12 
group by    dateDiff(month, dateAdd(hour, 11, createdAt), {ts '2015-02-28 23:59:59'}) 
order by    dateDiff(month, dateAdd(hour, 11, createdAt), {ts '2015-02-28 23:59:59'})
```

I am now converting this to the new system using .NET and LINQ.
I managed to write this LINQ query which gives me the same results.

```
from a in db.Accounts
where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Month", SqlFunctions.DateAdd("Hour", 11, a.createdAt), "2015-02-28 23:59:59") < 12
&& a.accountType == "business"
group a by SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Month", a.createdAt, "2015-02-28 23:59:59") into grp
orderby SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Month", grp.FirstOrDefault().createdAt, "2015-02-28 23:59:59")
select new ProgressViewModel.Data
{
     date = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Month", grp.FirstOrDefault().createdAt, "2015-02-28 23:59:59"),
     amount = grp.Count()
});
```

However, this query takes no less than 5 seconds to run, while with the first one (t-sql) it takes less than 1 second.

By using Glimpse, we could see the t-sql that that LINQ query generates. It has multiple sub selects and it is 5 times longer than the fast query.

How could I improve the LINQ query?

Comment: is there any chance to you turn above query to stored procedure and return the result and display in grid? if yes, that is the more efficient way

Comment: `grp.FirstOrDefauilt()` looks suspicious for one - didn't you mean `grp.Key`? Also, why not `dateAdd` the passed parameter, rather than the value in the database? That should allow you to use an index on `createdAt`, if there is one.

Comment: Can you please let us know what the generated LINQ query looks like?

Comment: I cannot find an equivalent of the condition "createdAt <= {ts '2015-02-28 23:59:59'} " inside your Linq version. The original query has 3 conditions for the Where, while the Linq one has only 2 conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt you actually want to use `FirstOrDefault()` at any point in your code.

BTW It looks like you are using LinqToSQL as your Linq provider. That thing is nasty, inefficient and downright buggy. You should switch to EntityFramework if its at all possible

Given that...perhaps you should try this...

```
var date = new Date(2015, 2, 28).AddDays(1);
var query = from account in context.Accounts
            where account.CreatedAt < date
            where account.accountType == "business"
            group account by 
                   SqlFunctions.DateDiff(
                            "Month", 
                             SqlFunctions.DateAdd(
                                   "Hour", 11, a.createdAt), 
                             date)
            into g
            where g.Key < 12
            order by g.Key ascending
            select new 
            {
                MonthsAgo = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count(),
            };
```

Comment: Hi Aron, your code solution was the cleanest and it worked as expected. However, there is no such thing as converting from linq to EF. They are different things, in our case we use EF and linq to query db (through EF). Anyway, thanks for your solution, selecting g.Key and adding the where g.Key < 12 made the whole difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this to bring it in to memory before the grouping:

```
from ca in (
    from a in db.Accounts
    where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Month", SqlFunctions.DateAdd("Hour", 11, a.createdAt), "2015-02-28 23:59:59") < 12 && a.accountType == "business"
    select a.createdAt).ToArray()
group a by new /* month diff */ into grp
orderby grp.Key
select new ProgressViewModel.Data
{
    date = grp.key,
    amount = grp.Count()
});
```

Comment: Damn...upvoted without really looking. Just realised this is a pretty bad query, since its done in memory

Comment: @Aron - Why is it bad to be in memory? Quite often it is faster than not bringing it in. It really depends what you're trying optimise.

Comment: So one thing, in this case, you could have at least transform the accounts into something with lower overhead.

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, I appreciated your answer however, I am going with the one that does not load the data into memory before the select. But I have done that in the past, as first loading data into memory then manipulating was faster than loading all in one hit from the db. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look I would investigate your section grp.FirstOrDefault - is this really what you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely go for a parametrized Stored Procedure in this case. You should also consider creating a covering index on the tables you need. These steps usually boost performance by a very noticable amount.